Azure Entra ID - Requiring Admin Consent - How to avoid this
Created simple test application which will ask user to do Entra-id login and once user log-in show his/her display name and role using streamlit and python.
EntraId login URL is as:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/[TenantID]/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=[ClientID]&response_type=code&redirect_uri=[MyLocalURL]&scope=User.Read+offline_access+openid+profile&state=[GUID]&nonce=[GUID]&prompt=select_account
Message we are getting:

Please allow me to share more details about settings as below:
In EntraId, did the app-registration and added api-permission as below 
Let me share enterprise application's settings :



With above settings also, we are still getting admin consent popup on customer's environment.
As per beautiful answer provided here: now have few basic questions as below

Is it mandatory that in "Permission Classification" blade we have to
add "User.Read" permission ?
If answer to above is yes, then there
is concern about security as this setting will be applicable at
tenant level, is it valid concern or this is the only way to resolve
this ?
Checked the URL(redirect url from my test app) in browser during redirect, it additionally includes [offline_access,openid,profile] is it mandatory to add those permission in API permission ?
Any other area, which might be causing this admin consent
popup


After granting consent the issue resolves?

Thank you for response, In API permission's blade :  Permission User.Read is added but customer is reluctant to do grant admin consent to tenant.  Still issue not resolved with this.

To avoid requiring the admin consent you have to either grant admin consent to the Microsoft Entra ID application or configure user consent in the tenant.

It is not mandatory to configure User.Read in Permission Classification blade.
The only way to resolve is to configure user consent and it is tenant level.
It is not mandatory to add offline_access, openid, profile in API permission blade.

Hence, to resolve the issue Go to Azure Portal -> Enterprise application -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings -> Enable the option Allow user consent for apps -> Save

Now the user will be able to consent:

If the application resides in one tenant and user resides in another tenant, then the setting must be made in the tenant where the user resides.
Reference:
Admin consent for applications with permissions like User.Read or Notes.ReadWrite.All? : r/AZURE

Appreciate your support, in my case the setting "Enterprise application -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings -> Enable the option Allow user consent for apps " is already set. As per your suggestion in
Home->App-registration -> App's API-permissions blade:
①. Configured permissions section should have "user.read"
②. Click on "✔ Grant admin consent for " must be done ?
Both ①,② are needed, is it correct ?

If you are granting admin consent then no need of setting the user consent

understood, just to double check my understanding:
A = "Enterprise application -> Consent and permissions -> User consent settings -> Enable the option Allow user consent for apps " is  selected...
B = In Home->App-registration -> App's API-permissions blade:  Configured permissions section should have "user.read" ....
C = Home->App-registration -> App's API-permissions blade : Click on "✔ Grant admin consent for "
Either A+B or C is needed, is it correct ?

Admin consent must be given where the app resides

Sure, will be marking it answer, just to summarize : Admin consent must be given where the app resides at tenant level , even if it is API permission is User.Read in my case, please answer as Yes or No to this, this will be helpful to mark it answer.

Yes. If you don't want to configure the user consent then yes

sorry for last question: In my case user consent is already set as per screenshot you shared in the answer then NO need of admin consent, and we already set User.Read permission in App-registration -> App's API-permissions blade, this should be enough to avoid admin consent pop-up. Please answer yes or no.

Is it a multitenant application?

This is Single tenant application

AFAIK the user consent setting must work if its not working then it needs user.read permissions must be granted with admin consent

Appreciate your kind response.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your answer "user.read permissions must be granted with admin consent" -> This means Home->App-registration -> App's API-permissions blade : Click on "✔ Grant admin consent for " is it correct ?

Yes that is the answer
